# File contains no section headers on Centos

Tags: centos, yum

When I tried to install CMake but writing the following

```
sudo yum install cmake
```

I got the following error

```
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo, line: 2
'<!doctype html>\n
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. One of your yum repository configuration files seem to be invalid. Can you show us the `/etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo` file?

Comment: Check if your header for the repo has correct brackets, example below
`[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch/debug
metalink=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-7&arch=$basearch`

Comment: it appears you downloaded a web page as your repo file instead of the plain-text contents of the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve by

```
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/mcepl-vim8-epel-7.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

As a safer solution, it's just enough to rename that repo file:

```
# cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
# mv <repo_file>.repo <repo_file>.repo.orig
```